# Capturing "Cancel" selection from GWT Activity.mayStop() response

Tags: java, events, gwt, android-activity

I have a GWT two column display.  The left column contains a `CellTable` with a list of users in the application.  When the user selects an user from the list, the right column displays the selected users details - which the user can edit.

I have my `Activity` wired up to use the `mayStop()` method so that before switching users, the system will attempt to save any unsaved changes the user has made - as long as there are no validation errors.

My question is about the behavior if there are validation errors. I have it wired to ask the user to discard the unsaved edits or return to the page and correct the issues.  My problem is that when the user hits cancel (to return and correct the errors), the cell table still "selects" the new user instead of keeping the user that's in the detail column selected. It appears that switching away from the user activity was canceled, but GWT is still making the `CellTable` selection.  Is there a way to capture the "Cancel" selection, or stop cell table selection from occurring?

Comment: Hard to suggest anything concrete, since you didn't put out any real code, but you could extend the `SelectionModel` that's attached to your `CellTable` and override the `setSelected(...)` method not to call `super.setSelected(...)` if there is a particular flag set somewhere. Again, without the specifics it's hard to suggest something solid, but that's one direction you can explore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the source of `PlaceController`, which triggers the eventual calls to `mayStop()` and `onStop()`, two different events are called, one for each. `PlaceChangeRequestEvent` goes first, indicating (predictably) that a change is being requested, but hasn't finished yet. This will call mayStop().

Then, if the user doesn't elect to cancel the change, `PlaceChangeEvent` gets fired, which calls `onStop()`. Otherwise, this will never be called.

My approach would be to base the actual selection in the left column based on these events. There isn't a handy way to stop/cancel selection, so there is no nice way to actually manage the selection, and delay it after the user provides their feedback. My thought would be to either

- Don't actually select when the user clicks, just effect the place change. Then, when `PlaceChangeEvent` is fired, actually make the selection. This is slightly gross, as I see no convenient way to cancel selection. Or
- Keep track of the last selected element after the user changes the selection (as opposed to the place). Listen for the `PlaceChangeRequestEvent`, and schedule a deferred command to select that original item, and listen for `PlaceChangeEvent` to skip the body of that command. This should work, since the alert presented to the user is blocking - I haven't actually tested it though.

If you are wiring the place changes into the url, you already need a PlaceChangeEvent handler to watch for the user clicking the browser forward/back buttons, so keep that in mind when you decide how to wire this - the place change should drive selection, just like selection needs to drive the place, but if the user clicks back, and cancels the place change, then the celltable should keep its original selection.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished an implementation of this based on input from a number of sources. Here is what I came up with that worked for me.

All cells in your cell widget need to be overridden to return true for handlesSelection(), like this:

```
/**
 * This text cell is designed for use in cell widgets that are tied to Places
 * and thus need to have the Activity/Presenter manage the selection to allow
 * for a mayStop() rejection of the navigation (user clicks cancel at prompt).
 */
public class PlaceTextCell extends TextCell
{   
    @Override
    public boolean handlesSelection()
    {
        // So that the selection model won't change the selection automatically.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you have to handle the selection event via a CellPreviewEvent (which occurs before the selection happens, unlike a SelectionChangeEvent). I used a DataGrid, but this should also work on a CellTable.

```
selectionDataGrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Dto>() {
    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Dto> event) {
        if(Event.getTypeInt(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) == Event.ONCLICK ||
       event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)
            {
            eventBus.fireEvent(new MySelectionChangeRequestEvent(event.getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

This fires a place change request event which calls PlaceController().goTo(). This will trigger a check of the Activity's mayStop(). Then your Activity needs to handle that interaction.

In my case, I have a singleton presenter. So I tell the presenter about the new Place. That call makes the update to the view to select the corresponding row.

Additionally, I still have the selectionModel working properly:

```
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        eventBus.fireEvent(new MySelectionChangeEvent(selectionModel.getSelectedObject()));
    }
});
```

So after this new row is selected, another event is fired to update another part of the UI based upon the new selection.

- The "Don't actually select when the user clicks" is handled by the
  custom cell override.
- The "effect the place change" part is handled by the CellPreviewHandler and the PlaceController.goTo(Place).
- The rest is just handled by your Activities and Places implementation.